# How to move children to a new parent, execpt the last child? (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a bit of JS code, which creates a new, custom HTML element. I need to move the child elements to the new parent, which is inside the custom element (I need two elements because of styling), but as elements put inside the tags are created first, I need to have all children of  moved to the last child of (I already create the new parent automatically). Note: jQuery solutions are acceptable.

Code:

```
    connectedCallback() {
        this.setAttribute('class', 'e1')
        const e1 = document.createElement('div')
        e1.setAttribute('class', 'e-content')
        this.appendChild(e1)
   }
```

```js
class ce extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.setAttribute('class', 'e1')
        const e1 = document.createElement('div')
        e1.setAttribute('class', 'e-content')
        this.appendChild(e1)
    }
}
customElements.define('custom-elem', ce);
```

```html
<custom-elem>
    <p>A child of custom-elem, which should go in the generated child of custom-elem (div with class e-content).</p>
</custom-elem>
```

Comment: Example: <custom-elem><p>foo</p></custom-elem>, I need <p>foo</p> to be moved to the div with the class "e-content".

Comment: I think it would be more helpful if you could create a fiddle by using the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar, so that it can be seen how the function is used.

Comment: Ok. I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding two statements (could likely be reduced to one) to the end of the `connectedCallback` function should cover it:

```js
class ce extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.setAttribute('class', 'e1')
        const e1 = document.createElement('div')
        e1.setAttribute('class', 'e-content')
        this.appendChild(e1)
        var pElement = this.getElementsByTagName('p')
        e1.appendChild(pElement[0])        
    }
}
customElements.define('custom-elem', ce);
```

```html
<custom-elem>
    <p>A child of custom-elem, which should go in the generated child of custom-elem (div with class e-content).</p>
</custom-elem>
```

Use the browser's inspector to see that the `<p>` element is moved to inside the `<div class="e-content">` element.